# Get the type from a - "createAction" function

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

There are two ways of creating an ngrx Action. One is to define a new class that implements the Action class and the other is to use the "createAction" function. Is there a way to get to the typings of an action that was created using the "createAction" method?

For example if I have this action:

```
export const getWorker = createAction(
  '[Worker Api] Get Worker',
  props<{ workerId: number }>()
);
```

I would like to get the workerId in an effect that listens to that action:

```
getWorker$ = createEffect(() => {
return this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType(WeatherApiActions.getWorker),
  switchMap((action: { type: string, workerId: number }) => this.workerService.getWorker(action.workerId)),
  map((worker: IWorker) => WeatherApiActions.getWorkerSuccess({ worker }))
)})
```

As you so I had to write the type myself. This makes the effect tightly coupled to the action and this is a huge drawback. So my question is: Do I must use the first way of creating an action in order to have the action payload typings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I exactly needed it when I wanted to share some code inside my effect and figured it out.

Answer to your question is, No. You can get Action type with a simple code.

Using `ReturnType` utility type, you can extract Action type from the function created by `createAction`.

Having the action created as below,

```
const getWorker = createAction(
  '[Worker Api] Get Worker',
  props<{ workerId: number }>()
);
```

`ReturnType<typeof getWorker>` results in *type* `{ workerId: number } & TypedAction<'[Worker Api] Get Worker'>`.

If you look at the declaration code of `ofType` operator function in the library, you'll see it also uses `ReturnType` utility.

Answer (score -1):

I'm relatively new to ng/ngrx and the like, but it seems that part of the reason for using the create* helper methods is to get better type support. I had this same issue and one of my effects went from this:

```
  authSignup = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.SIGNUP_START),
    switchMap((signupAction: AuthActions.SignupStart) => {
      return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(
  ...
```

To this:

```
  authSignup = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(AuthActions.signupStart),
      switchMap(({ email, password }) => {
        return this.http
          .post<AuthResponseData>(
  ...
```

The action looks like:

```
export const signupStart = createAction(
  "[Auth] Signup Start",
  props<{ email: string; password: string }>()
);
```

It took a bit for me to figure this out; the switchMap now *knows* what the props for the action are. And, at least in the latest VSCode, I got IntelliSense help when entering the parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how this is answering the question. The problem to me is that both the switchMap and the createAction have to define the  payload type thus forcing you into code duplication and fault sensitive code.